# concatenate fastq files in a directory

Tags: bash, merge, upload, cron, fastq

I have a file uploader, resumable.js, which takes a file and breaks it into 1MB 'chunks' and than sends over the files 1MB at a time. So after an upload I have a directory with thousands, sometimes millions of individual fastq files. I can concatenate all of these 'chunks' back into the files original state with this line of code..

```
cat file_name.* > merged.fastq
```

How would I go about concatenating the files back into its original state without manually running this script in the command line? Should I set up some bash script to handle this issue, maybe a cronjob? Any ideas to solve this issue are greatly appreciated.

ANSWER: For what its worth I used this npm module and it works great.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/joiner

Comment: How does your uploader upload the files? What is the transport mechanism?

Comment: https://github.com/23/resumable.js/

Comment: And what does your backend look like? Is there an event/request for "finished uploading"? You could also just check on each upload if the upload is finished it looks like.

Comment: best to summarize the important points of `resumable` for everyone AND edit into your question, rather than expect people to go and search for info required to answer your question. Also if  you say " with thousands, sometimes millions of individual fastq files." I almost certain the linux command line cannot process more than, hmmm, maybe 10,000 (small) filenames in one go. The `cat *` will generate an error message about "too many arguments" or similar. Good luck!

Comment: "I almost certain the linux command line cannot process more than..." That's not really a problem, just use xargs. The problem is we don't even know what's the notification mechanism... If there's a notification at all, or a gesture, say, creating a specially named file after upload finishes (which is very easy to realize on the client side), then there are a million ways to concatenate them afterwards. I would run a daemon to watch for the notification/gesture.

Comment: @shellter Sorry what point are you trying to make? Why are you piping the output of `cat *` into `xargs`? In this case, if you want to concat a large number of files, just do `find . -print0 | xargs -0 cat >merged.fastq`, or better yet, use `find`'s builtin xargs capability: `find . -exec cat {} + >merged.fastq`.

Comment: ok, on the back end.. in the /upload POST route I have a variable called status, and I have an if statement conosle.log "successful" when the upload is finished.. So now I have starting point, but don't know how I should approach this issue